# Trying to appending a text in a new line to an existing file in Java?

Tags: java, string, file, io

[How to append text to an existing file in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625234/how-to-append-text-to-an-existing-file-in-java)

I am using the method mentioned in the solution and i am taking user input.
But the text is appending with the last word. is there any way to add an new line there?

```
  Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in); 
        System.out.print("Enter a string: ");  
        String str= sc.nextLine(); 
        try {
            Files.write(Paths.get("C:\\Users\\souravpal\\Documents\\Bandicam\\buddy.txt"), str.getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
        }catch (IOException e) {
            //exception handling left as an exercise for the reader
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use the new line character \n in your str variable if you want to move to the next line.

```
String str = "\n" + sc.nextLine();
```

You also should put it before the input becouse you will append it at the end of the file.

Comment: You should avoid specific new line separators such as "\n" or "\r\n" that depends on the OS.

Comment: Interesting. I was using \n on all OS and this is working. Why do you think it's working only on windows?

Comment: Check this out: 
https://www.baeldung.com/java-string-newline

Answer (score 0):

use the System.lineSeparator() constant that applies at runtime and compatible with all OS.

```
Files.write(Paths.get("C:\\Users\\souravpal\\Documents\\Bandicam\\buddy.txt"),
                    (System.lineSeparator() + str).getBytes(),StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
```